# Facebook: How to successfully paste formatted text into a group post?

Tags: facebook, copy-paste, text

On Facebook, when creating a new post to be posted into a Group (as opposed to onto a standard personal or company page), Facebook allows you to [add some simple formatting to the post](https://www.facebook.com/help/1978961375733163).

If you highlight some text in the compose view for such a post, Facebook pops up a little toolbar that allows the simple formatting to be added to the selected text.

[image: Facebook post formatting toolbar]

However, if formatted text is *pasted* into the compose view, all of the formatting is lost, and the text is pasted in without formatting.

Even if selecting, copying, and pasting formatted text within that Facebook compose view itself, the formatting is still lost upon paste, as in this in-progress post, where a copy was made of the content via copy and then paste:

[image: Facebook post compose window showing formatted and unformatted text]

This is highly inconvenient in a number of situations. For example, when copying a block of formatted text from one Facebook group into a new post in another Facebook group, all of the formatting must be manually re-applied after pasting, which is very time-consuming.

Is there a method to successfully be able to paste formatted text into a Facebook group post?

Comment: A very good question, if you find how to solve please share the solution